# Animating object inside UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, animation, uipageviewcontroller

I have a button inside UIPageViewController. I added animation to it (hide/show)

Once I go to another controller by clicking other buttons then I go back to the the view controller with animating button, I couldn't click any button anymore.

I tried to remove the animation on the button and everything works fine again so I'm guessing it's the animation that I'm having a problem with.

Here's my code for the button's animation:

```
    CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
    theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    theAnimation.duration=1.0;
    theAnimation.repeatCount=3;
    theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
    theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    [helloGuestButton.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```